# How to generate unit tests for controller using the scaffolding template Test.groovy?

Tags: unit-testing, testing, grails, controller, scaffolding

If I generate a contoller using the command "create-controller" Grails generates the contoller and a unit test (using the template /src/templates/scaffolding/Test.groovy).

After changing bits of the template I now want to generate the unit tests anew but Grails won't generate them. I tried:

- `"create-unit-test"` but this will use the template /src/templates/testing/UnitTest.groovy
  and 
  `"create-integration-test"` will use the template /src/templates/testing/Generic.groovy

So how can I generate unit test for controller using the Test.groovy template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When creating artifacts or using scaffolding, Grails uses templates to create the domain classes, controllers, views, etc. The default templates are part of the Grails distribution for out of the box behaviour, but can be customized for project specific needs.

Copies the the templates used by Grails during code generation to your project directory:

```
$ grails install-templates

src/templates/
├── artifacts
│   ├── Tests.groovy
│   ├── ...
├── scaffolding
│   ├── Test.groovy
│   ├── ...
└── war
    └── web.xml
```

The artifacts directory contains the templates used by the create-* commands.
The scaffolding directory contains templates used by the generate-* commands.
The war directory contains the web.xml template used to generate the deployment descriptor.

So you need to edit:

- `src/templates/artifacts/Tests.groovy` file, when execute `grails create-unit-test` or `grails create-integration-test` commands.
- `src/templates/scaffolding/Test.groovy` when execute `grails generate-all` or `grails
  generate-controller` commands.

In your case regenerate your controller test and **overwrite only your test file**:

```
$ grails generate-controller com.arturoherrero.Post
| Generating controller for domain class com.arturoherrero.Post
> File /grails-app/controllers/com/arturoherrero/PostController.groovy already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] n
> File /test/unit/com/arturoherrero/PostControllerTests.groovy already exists. Overwrite?[y,n,a] y
| Finished generation for domain class com.arturoherrero.Post
```